# ProcessBuilder - cannot execute the conda command

Tags: java, command-line, anaconda, processbuilder

When I run the following command in command line I get no problems and the environment changes to jaydev

`conda activate jaydev`
my command line after this looks something like this `(jaydev) C:\Users\jay dev>`

(I am writing this command in windows command line and not in anaconda prompt , I have made the necessary configurations to do so)

But when I use process builder and try executing the same command it does not execute the problem is seen below.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("conda", "activate", "jaydev");]
Process p = pb.start();
```

error -

```
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "conda": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 1 more
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try with this `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C conda activate jaydev");` instead of ProcessBuilder.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
    List<String> processParameters = new ArrayList<String>();
    processParameters.add("cmd.exe");
    processParameters.add("/C");
    processParameters.add("conda");
    processParameters.add("activate");
    processParameters.add("myENV");

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(processParameters);
```